# Registro de usuario com Vue js e laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Criei uma pagina de login com vue.js.
Mandei as informações para um controller no laravel para criar um usuário.
Depois de criar o usuário, estou tentando redirecionar para home,com o usuário autenticado, mas quando redireciona para home, cai na tela de login.

**Requisição Vue**

```
register(){
        
        axios.post('/api/register', this.form)
            .then(response => {
                window.location.href = "/home";
            });
    }
```

**Rota API**

```
Route::post('register', 'Api\RegisterController@register');
```

**Controller Laravel**

```
 public function register(Request $request){
    

    $data = $request->validated();

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    Auth::login($user);
    Auth::guard()->login($user);
     // Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);


    return response()->json(['message' => 'Salvo com sucesso.','user' => $user]);
}
```

**Rota WEB, que esta acessando após o registro:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::get('/home', function(){
      return view('home')
  });
});
```

Eu tentei com o código redirecionar para a home autenticado, mas esta indo para a tela de login, por causa do middlware.

Tem algum jeito de ir para a tela home autenticado automatico após o registro, sem ter que se logar?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Ao invés de retornar uma mensagem de sucesso sempre, use uma condicional para verificar se, de fato, o login foi realizado e aí sim poderá retornar uma mensagem de erro ou sucesso.

Comment: Certo, mas tem algum jeito de ir para a tela home autenticado automatico após o registro?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Um possível motivo é porque quando você usa rotas dentro do prefix "api", a sessão não está iniciada. O que você pode fazer:

No arquivo: `app/Http/Kernel.php`, procure pelo `$middlewareGroups` `"api"`.

Adicione os middleware para iniciar sessão e relacionados com cookies.

Vai ficar +- assim:

```
// ...

        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
// ...
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-groups

O seu guard, provavelmente (se default), está utilizando "web", no auth.php - que utiliza sessions/cookies.

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

E o middleware de "api" não tem sessions por padrão (no RouteServiceProvider, você vai ver que para rotas /api, é utilizado o middleware group "api" - que só utiliza dois middleware definidos no kernel: throttle:api e SubstituteBindings).

#### Sugestões:

Apenas `Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);` é suficiente. Não precisar chamar os outros métodos de login.

Comment: Obrigado Eduardo.
Funcionou colocando, \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, dentro do, protected $middleware.